How to Handle huge requests with azure function queue trigger?
We're using azure function app for our application backend, for async tasks we're using Queue triggers provided by function app.
In our app, when an user performs certain task, it would trigger approximately 50 async executions (means triggering the Queue function in the same function app)
While testing this flow i got experienced a delay in responses, when i try to debug and read from blogs, i got to know that azure Queue only support 32 concurrent tasks into the queue.
So here when i try to request the data from the Backend while async tasks > 32, i'm experiencing a delay until the tasks are freed up

The maximum batchSize is 32.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python#host-json
How can i handle more number of requests, i need to support large scale requests for this app, how can this 32 is sufficient ? Any solutions ?

Is your Azure Function App in the same Region as the user and their activity? i.e. you don't have network-latency issues?

You linked to a document for Azure Functions v1 which is old now - can you upgrade to something more recent - Azure Functions is on v4 now...

we're not facing any n/w latency issues, this is specific to queue, we're expericing the delays while pushing the msg to queue

Can you share some code? It might help people suggest how to mitigate the problem. For example, you mention that you experience a delay in the "Backend" until tasks are freed up; it would help us to know what that Backend function is doing and what the wait mechanism is. You don't need to post the whole code, just the relevant functions.
